# jQuery FIND div local to the button clicked on

Tags: jquery, html, find, closest

I am trying to locate a DIV that is located near to the  button I am clicking on but cant seem to locate it... Code is as below. Basically my use of closest or find or prev of children or parent does not seem to locate the ".tweetButtonOverlayWrapper" DIV to toggle the class as per jQuery call... Any ideas what I am doing wrong???

**jQUERY:**

```
$('.tweetActionsButtonWrapper a').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('div.tweetButtonOverlayWrapper').toggleClass('tweetButtonOverlayWrapperON');
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
<li>

<!-- Overlay Buttons -->
<div class="tweetButtonOverlayWrapper" id="tweet"><p>content</p></div>
<!-- end of Overlay Buttons -->

<div class="tweetDetailContentWrapper">
<div class="tweetAvatarBorder"></div><div class="tweetAvatar"><p>content</p></div>
<div class="tweetDetailWrapper">
<p class="tweetDetailAutor"><a href="#">@name</a> <span class="tweetDetailAutorTimeStamp">15 minutes ago</span></p>
<p>This is where the interesting tweet will sit... Easily allows us to display all 140 characters which is the maximum any tweet will allow....</p>
</div>
<div class="tweetActionsButtonWrapper"><a href="#" class="timeSegment-link tweetActionsButtonNoRightAlign" title="">More actions</a></div>
</div>

</li>

<li>

<!-- Overlay Buttons -->
<div class="tweetButtonOverlayWrapper" id="tweet"><p>content</p></div>
<!-- end of Overlay Buttons -->

<div class="tweetDetailContentWrapper">
<div class="tweetAvatarBorder"></div><div class="tweetAvatar"><p>content</p></div>
<div class="tweetDetailWrapper">
<p class="tweetDetailAutor"><a href="#">@name</a> <span class="tweetDetailAutorTimeStamp">15 minutes ago</span></p>
<p>This is where the interesting tweet will sit... Easily allows us to display all 140 characters which is the maximum any tweet will allow....</p>
</div>
<div class="tweetActionsButtonWrapper"><a href="#" class="timeSegment-link tweetActionsButtonNoRightAlign" title="">More actions</a></div>
</div>

</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tweetButtonOverlayWrapper is sibling of the parent of 'a', the following should do it.

```
$('.tweetActionsButtonWrapper a').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent()
           .siblings('div.tweetButtonOverlayWrapper')
           .toggleClass('tweetButtonOverlayWrapperON');
    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dhruvasagar/ZzfrN/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can't find your element because `div.tweetButtonOverlayWrapper` is not actually parent for your `a`. This will work:

```
$('.tweetActionsButtonWrapper a').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('div.tweetDetailContentWrapper')
           .siblings('div.tweetButtonOverlayWrapper')
           .toggleClass('tweetButtonOverlayWrapperON');
    return false;

});
```

code: http://jsfiddle.net/ZzfrN/

Comment: Thanks - just implement that and it does find the DIV and toggle the class yep - but... We have a list of <li>s here which all contain similar code, when you list them all together and click on the <li> below's <a> button it toggles the first list <li> item DIV on and off - not its own version...